# apache Spark with hive

Tags: maven, apache-spark, spark-hive

How can i read/write data from/to hive? 
Is it necessary to compile spark with hive profile to interact with hive? 
which maven dependencies are required to interact with hive?

i could not find a well documentation to follow step by step to get working with hive.

Currently Here is my code

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("test"))
    val HiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
    val sqlCon = new SQLContext(sc)
val schemaString = "Date:string,Open:double,High:double,Low:double,Close:double,Volume:double,Adj_Close:double"
val schema =
  StructType(
    schemaString.split(",").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName.split(":")(0),
      getFieldTypeInSchema(fieldName.split(":")(1)), true)))
val rdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://45.55.159.119:9000/yahoo_stocks.csv")
//val rdd = sc.parallelize(arr)
val rowRDDx = noHeader.map(p => {
  var list: collection.mutable.Seq[Any] = collection.mutable.Seq.empty[Any]
  var index = 0
  val regex = rowSplittingRegexBuilder(Seq(","))
  var tokens = p.split(regex)
  tokens.foreach(value => {
    var valType = schema.fields(index).dataType
    var returnVal: Any = null
    valType match {
      case IntegerType => returnVal = value.toString.toInt
      case DoubleType => returnVal = value.toString.toDouble
      case LongType => returnVal = value.toString.toLong
      case FloatType => returnVal = value.toString.toFloat
      case ByteType => returnVal = value.toString.toByte
      case StringType => returnVal = value.toString
      case TimestampType => returnVal = value.toString
    }
    list = list :+ returnVal
    index += 1
  })
  Row.fromSeq(list)
})
val df = sqlCon.applySchema(rowRDDx, schema)
HiveContext.sql("create table yahoo_orc_table (date STRING, open_price FLOAT, high_price FLOAT, low_price FLOAT, close_price FLOAT, volume INT, adj_price FLOAT) stored as orc")
df.saveAsTable("hive", "org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc", SaveMode.Append)
```

I am getting following exception

```
15/10/12 14:57:36 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager 
15/10/12 14:57:38 INFO scheduler.EventLoggingListener: Logging events to hdfs://host:9000/spark/logs/local-1444676256555
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type 
Exception Details: 
  Location: 
    org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Pmod.inputType()Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/AbstractDataType; @3: areturn 
  Reason: 
    Type 'org/apache/spark/sql/types/NumericType$' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/spark/sql/types/AbstractDataType' (from method signature) 
  Current Frame: 
    bci: @3 
    flags: { } 
    locals: { 'org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Pmod' } 
    stack: { 'org/apache/spark/sql/types/NumericType$' } 
  Bytecode: 
    0000000: b200 63b0 

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595) 
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895) 
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2066) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.FunctionRegistry$$anonfun$4.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:267) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.FunctionRegistry$$anonfun$4.apply(FunctionRegistry.scala:267) 
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.FunctionRegistry$.expression(FunctionRegistry.scala:267) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.FunctionRegistry$.<init>(FunctionRegistry.scala:148) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.FunctionRegistry$.<clinit>(FunctionRegistry.scala) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:414) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry(HiveContext.scala:413) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.<init>(UDFRegistration.scala:39) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:203) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:72)
```

thanks

Comment: it's probably a java versions incompatibility. which java are you using? which java did you use to compile spark with?

Comment: first be sure not to have dependencies you don't really need. (i was facing the same problem and it was enough to remove a dependency i wasn't using at all). then give a try with java 1.6

Comment: i just have maven dependencies of spark_core,spark_sql and spark_hive only.

Comment: this kind of errors usually means that libraries you used in compile time are different than libraries you're using in runtime and maybe some of compile times ones have dependencies with different version of java. if you checked this and it's all right i'm sorry but i have no more ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dr_stein mentioned, this error is usually due to incompatible compile time and runtime JDK versions, such as running JDK 1.6 with 1.7 compiled jars.

I would also check if your hive libraries reflect the correct versions and if your hive server is also running on the same JDK as you are.

you can also try running with the -noverify option, which will disable verification.

Comment: -noverify option should be given as part of spark-submit command?

Comment: you can pass spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-noverify" to spark-submit